# How to run GPGPU Memory Testing

Tags: memory, cuda, graphics-processing-unit

We use a lot of GPGPU computing (mostly with CUDA, but some OpenCL).  Often when users are running code, the code errors out with a memory error on only one of our hosts.  I suspect one of the cards is faulty.  Sometimes it brings down the whole system and sometimes the program just bombs out.

**What are the easiest, fastest, and most thorough ways to fully test GPUs for possible failures?**

I know there are programs that are part of nvidia's CUDA SDK:

```
   deviceQuery
   nvidia-smi
```

But I need something much more thorough.  Suggestions?  Experiences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The de facto standard seems to be [CUDA GPU Memtest](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cudagpumemtest/).  As @c2h5oh mentioned, it looks like it's based on memtest86 test patterns so I'm sure it does a good job.  It runs relatively quickly on the high end GPUs I'm testing (30 minutes on a Quadro 6000 and 20 minutes on a Tesla C2075).  It runs inside the OS (unlike, memtest) so monitoring is a bit different.  You'll probably want to output stdout and stderr to a file to look at later.  So consider running it something like this in case you lose your terminal output you can look up what the tests found:

```
cuda_memtest 2>cuda_memtest.stderr 1>cuda_memtest.stdout &
tail -f cuda_memtest.stdout &
tail -f cuda_memtest.stderr &
```

You'll also want to make sure that no one is using the system and/or cards.  You can set the GPUs to exclusive mode using:

```
nvidia-smi --compute-mode=EXCLUSIVE_PROCESS
```

Here are some of the output from sample runs of both the Quadro and the Tesla in case you're interested in what test info is given:

```
[09/07/2012 11:56:22][hydro][0]:Running cuda memtest, version 1.2.2
[09/07/2012 11:56:23][hydro][0]:Warning: Getting serial number failed
[09/07/2012 11:56:23][hydro][0]:NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  295.41  Fri Apr  6 23:18:58 PDT 2012
[09/07/2012 11:56:23][hydro][0]:num_gpus=1
[09/07/2012 11:56:23][hydro][0]:Device name=Quadro 6000, global memory size=6441992192
[09/07/2012 11:56:23][hydro][0]:major=2, minor=0
[09/07/2012 11:56:24][hydro][0]:Attached to device 0 successfully.
[09/07/2012 11:56:24][hydro][0]:Allocated 6040 MB
[09/07/2012 11:56:24][hydro][0]:Test0 [Walking 1 bit]
[09/07/2012 11:56:30][hydro][0]:Test0 finished in 5.7 seconds
[09/07/2012 11:56:30][hydro][0]:Test1 [Own address test]
[09/07/2012 11:56:33][hydro][0]:Test1 finished in 3.5 seconds
[09/07/2012 11:56:33][hydro][0]:Test2 [Moving inversions, ones&zeros]
[09/07/2012 11:57:05][hydro][0]:Test2 finished in 32.3 seconds
[09/07/2012 11:57:05][hydro][0]:Test3 [Moving inversions, 8 bit pat]
[09/07/2012 11:57:37][hydro][0]:Test3 finished in 31.9 seconds
[09/07/2012 11:57:37][hydro][0]:Test4 [Moving inversions, random pattern]
[09/07/2012 11:57:53][hydro][0]:Test4 finished in 15.9 seconds
[09/07/2012 11:57:53][hydro][0]:Test5 [Block move, 64 moves]
[09/07/2012 11:57:59][hydro][0]:Test5 finished in 6.3 seconds
[09/07/2012 11:57:59][hydro][0]:Test6 [Moving inversions, 32 bit pat]
[09/07/2012 12:18:46][hydro][0]:Test6 finished in 1246.6 seconds
[09/07/2012 12:18:46][hydro][0]:Test7 [Random number sequence]
[09/07/2012 12:19:06][hydro][0]:Test7 finished in 19.8 seconds
[09/07/2012 12:19:06][hydro][0]:Test8 [Modulo 20, random pattern]
[09/07/2012 12:19:06][hydro][0]:test8[mod test]: p1=0x13472f5f, p2=0xecb8d0a0
[09/07/2012 12:20:34][hydro][0]:Test8 finished in 88.0 seconds
[09/07/2012 12:20:34][hydro][0]:Test10 [Memory stress test]
[09/07/2012 12:20:34][hydro][0]:Test10 with pattern=0x55f6c69858704128
[09/07/2012 12:21:11][hydro][0]:Test10 finished in 36.8 seconds
[09/07/2012 12:21:11][hydro][0]:Test0 [Walking 1 bit]
[09/07/2012 12:21:16][hydro][0]:Test0 finished in 5.8 seconds



[09/06/2012 18:49:07][hydro][0]:Running cuda memtest, version 1.2.2
[09/06/2012 18:49:10][hydro][0]:Warning: Getting serial number failed
[09/06/2012 18:49:10][hydro][0]:NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  295.41  Fri Apr  6 23:18:58 PDT 2012
[09/06/2012 18:49:10][hydro][0]:num_gpus=1
[09/06/2012 18:49:10][hydro][0]:Device name=Tesla C2075, global memory size=5636292608
[09/06/2012 18:49:10][hydro][0]:major=2, minor=0
[09/06/2012 18:49:11][hydro][0]:Attached to device 0 successfully.
[09/06/2012 18:49:11][hydro][0]:Allocated 5273 MB
[09/06/2012 18:49:11][hydro][0]:Test0 [Walking 1 bit]
[09/06/2012 18:49:22][hydro][0]:Test0 finished in 11.1 seconds
[09/06/2012 18:49:22][hydro][0]:Test1 [Own address test]
[09/06/2012 18:49:25][hydro][0]:Test1 finished in 3.1 seconds
[09/06/2012 18:49:25][hydro][0]:Test2 [Moving inversions, ones&zeros]
[09/06/2012 18:49:52][hydro][0]:Test2 finished in 27.4 seconds
[09/06/2012 18:49:52][hydro][0]:Test3 [Moving inversions, 8 bit pat]
[09/06/2012 18:50:20][hydro][0]:Test3 finished in 27.9 seconds
[09/06/2012 18:50:20][hydro][0]:Test4 [Moving inversions, random pattern]
[09/06/2012 18:50:34][hydro][0]:Test4 finished in 13.7 seconds
[09/06/2012 18:50:34][hydro][0]:Test5 [Block move, 64 moves]
[09/06/2012 18:50:39][hydro][0]:Test5 finished in 5.5 seconds
[09/06/2012 18:50:39][hydro][0]:Test6 [Moving inversions, 32 bit pat]
[09/06/2012 19:08:34][hydro][0]:Test6 finished in 1074.9 seconds
[09/06/2012 19:08:34][hydro][0]:Test7 [Random number sequence]
[09/06/2012 19:08:51][hydro][0]:Test7 finished in 17.1 seconds
[09/06/2012 19:08:51][hydro][0]:Test8 [Modulo 20, random pattern]
[09/06/2012 19:08:51][hydro][0]:test8[mod test]: p1=0x63136646, p2=0x9cec99b9
[09/06/2012 19:10:10][hydro][0]:Test8 finished in 78.4 seconds
[09/06/2012 19:10:10][hydro][0]:Test10 [Memory stress test]
[09/06/2012 19:10:10][hydro][0]:Test10 with pattern=0x26341d134a89ac2b
[09/06/2012 19:10:39][hydro][0]:Test10 finished in 29.0 seconds
```

Comment: How can I run this test in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Google: Memtest + GPU: any of the 3 first results seem to be a valid answer. No personal experience.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cudagpumemtest/

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/Memory-Tweak/CUDA-MemTest.shtml

https://simtk.org/home/memtest/

Comment: Of course I googled it.  I was wondering if anyone knew how all these compared (easiest, fastest, most thorough) for finding errors, testing the features of different cards, etc.

Comment: The first one claims to be replicating memtest86/memtest86+ testing patterns on GPU and that's recommendation enough - those tests will be thorough (and if the tool is anything like memtest86/+ there will be almost no user interaction - start & watch progress). Since you specifically requested memory testing none of the above will test anything but memory.